# Conway Complex Analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following exercise

[image]

I've tried to use the facts of Conway's chapter VI section 2, but I can't find a good way to solve this. Any tips?

Comment: Mobius transformation + Schwarz lemma.

Comment: Should we assume those are the only zeros?